# Converting Inches to Centimeters using Jframe

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, jframe

I'm new to using Jframe on Netbeans and our professor told us to create a program that converts Inches into Centimeter. He also told us to use Jbutton "Convert, Clear and Exit" I've already finish the "Clear and Exit" and my problem is how do I convert here using Jframe. I'm kinda confuse using it.

```
INCH = Inches
CENT = Centimeter

private void CLEARActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    INCH.setText("");
    CENT.setText("");
}                                     

private void EXITActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    System.exit(0);
}                                    

private void ABTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    AboutFormDesign e = new AboutFormDesign();
    e.setVisible(true);
}                                   

private void INCHKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                              

   char EMMAN = evt.getKeyChar();
   if(!(Character.isDigit(EMMAN) 
           ||(EMMAN == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) 
           ||(EMMAN==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)))
   {
       getToolkit().beep();
       evt.consume();



    }
}                             

private void ConvertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        



}                                       

private void CENTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Comment: Not at all. A `JFrame` is just a GUI-Component that represents a window on the screen ([javadoc]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not complete enough to fully understand, but it looks like you're trying to use a KeyListener within some text component, perhaps a JTextField, and if so, **don't**. Accept that field's text on enter press using an ActionListener, or from response to an ActionListener attached to a JButton, and then analyze it. If your further stuck, improve your question please.

Regarding:

> and my problem is how do I convert here using Jframe

You first create a JPanel, place your components into the JPanel, place that JPanel into a JFrame and display it as is well described in the [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).